# URL rewrite with add_rewrite_rule and attachment_id

Tags: attachments, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to add a rewrite rule to make this:

```
mysite/?attachment_id=106
```

look like this:

```
mysite/series/106
```

I've looked everywhere in this site and others and it's very confusing because there are lots of different ways to do it.
I've tried editing the `functions.php` file in my themes folder, adding this at the beginning of the file:

```
add_rewrite_rule('series/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?attachment_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

And the latest one I've tried:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa56345_query_vars' );

function wpa56345_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'attachment_id';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa56345_rewrites' );

function wpa56345_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'series/(\d+)/?$',
        'index.php?attachment_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Comment: Your english seems as good as your coding instincts, kudos for that and for the good question, and welcome to WPSE :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the code suggested below in *functions.php* of your desired theme, it worked for me with WP 3.4: [http://matty.co.za/2009/11/custom-url-rewrites-in-wordpress/](http://matty.blog/custom-url-rewrites-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Please add the important part of the answer from the link, that way even if the link expires in the future, your answer will still be useful.

Answer (score 4):

This seem to work for me:

```
// Add your query variable

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
function my_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    array_push($query_vars, 'attachment_id');
    return $query_vars;
}

// Add your rule

add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'my_rewrite_rules_array' );
function my_rewrite_rules_array( $rules ) {
    $my_rules = array();
    $my_rules['series/(\d+)/?$'] = 'index.php?attachment_id=$matches[1]';
    return $my_rules + $rules;
}

// Flush the rules if your rule does not exist

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_flush_rules' );
function my_flush_rules() {
    if (!$rules = get_option('rewrite_rules'))
        $rules = array();

    if (!isset($rules['series/(\d+)/?$'])) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}
```

And also, if you want to debug rules, there's a useful snippet:

```
// Uncomment add_action to see what's happening

//add_action('wp', 'debug_rules');
function debug_rules() {
    global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    echo $wp->matched_rule . ' | ' . $wp_rewrite->rules[$wp->matched_rule];
    print_r($wp_rewrite->rules);
    exit();
}
```

Hope it helps.