# Image Attachment Url Rewrite

Tags: permalinks, themes, url-rewriting, attachments

I'm having an issue with url rewriting for a theme I'm making, which is basically a gallery theme based on the roots theme. Here's how the site navigation works:

- Home Page (With Tiled Image Gallery) (Images link to parent pages) Current URL -  `domain.com`
- Parent Page (With Tiled Image Gallery) (Images link to attachment page along with #id to link to the clicked image ). Current URL - `domain.com/landscapes`
- Attachment Page (With ALL full size images attached to the parent post). Current URL - `domain.com/landscapes/image-title/#id`

What I would like to do is to remove the image title from the attachment page URL and replace it with gallery so that the URL reads `domain.com/landscapes/gallery/#id`

My content-image.php uses `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to get the image urls. With pretty permalinks disabled i get an image URL like `domain.com/index.php?attachment_id=205`

When checking with pretty URL with the Rewrite Rules Inspector Plugin, that URL (`domain.com/landscapes/image-title/#id`) gets 2 matches which are as follows:

RULE 1: `(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$`

Rewrite 1: `index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]`

RULE 2: `[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$`

Rewrite 2: `index.php?attachment=$matches[1]`

From what I understand, The second rule is the one that is being applied in this case, but I have no clue what to change it to. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer. I used the code as per https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56426/37472 and changed all references of `'series'` to `'gallery'`.

That added the required rewritre rule to parse a link like `domain.com/landscapes/gallery/123/` to `index.php?attachment_id=123`.

My assumption was that wordpress would display the default permalink that is generated by `get_permalink()` in the `domain.com/landscapes/gallery/123/` format. It does not. However, I used a simple workaround in my gallery script to generate the anchor links in the required format, which is different for the home page, sub pages and parent/other pages. The script uses isotope and lazy load to load the galleries http://pastie.org/8294032.

For the different format of the pages, i modified the `my_rewrite_rules_array( $rules )` function as follows:

```
function my_rewrite_rules_array( $rules ) {
    $my_rules = array();
    $my_rules['gallery/(\d+)/?$'] = 'index.php?attachment_id=$matches[1]';
    $my_rules['(\w+)/gallery/(\d+)/?$'] = 'index.php?attachment_id=$matches[2]';
    $my_rules['(\w+)/(\w+)/gallery/(\d+)/?$'] = 'index.php?attachment_id=$matches[3]';
    return $my_rules + $rules;
}
```